# l3keys: Synonymous keys not working

Tags: expl3, l3keys

In the key-value interface of one of my commands, there is a key `name style`, and I have defined an alternative name for it as follows:

```
, name-style    .meta:n             = { name~style = #1 }
, name-style    .value_required:n   = true
```

However, as you can see from the following example, `name-style` does not behave the same as `name style`. What is the reason for this and how should I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\RequirePackage { amsmath, amsthm }

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[name-in-link]{create-theorem}

\CreateTheorem { theorem } { number-within = subsection, create-numberless-version  }

\SetTheorem { theorem }
  {
    name-style = { % "name style" works
      , heading style = \color{blue}\textsc
      , crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
      , Crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
      , numbering style = \color{red}\textbf
    }
  }

\begin{document}

Current language: \languagename


\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
  In english.
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
  In english.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
  An unnumbered theorem.
\end{theorem*}

\Cref{thm1,thm2}


\end{document}
```

Here is the desired result:

[image]

Below is the complete set-up of keys, for your reference:

```
\keys_define:nn { create-theorem-setting }
  {
    , name                        .code:n             = { \exp_args:Ne \NameTheorem { \l__crthm_current_env_tl } { #1 } }
    , name                        .value_required:n   = true
    , name~style                  .code:n             = { \exp_args:Ne \NameTheorem { \l__crthm_current_env_tl } { #1 } }
    , name~style                  .value_required:n   = true
    , name-style                  .meta:n             = { name~style = #1 }
    , name-style                  .value_required:n   = true
    , name style                  .meta:n             = { name~style = #1 }
    , name style                  .value_required:n   = true
    , parent~counter              .code:n             = { \crthm_counter_within:en { \l__crthm_current_env_tl } { #1 } }
    , parent~counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , parent-counter              .meta:n             = { parent~counter = #1 }
    , parent-counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , parent counter              .meta:n             = { parent~counter = #1 }
    , parent counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , number~within               .meta:n             = { parent~counter = #1 }
    , number~within               .value_required:n   = true
    , number-within               .meta:n             = { parent~counter = #1 }
    , number-within               .value_required:n   = true
    , number within               .meta:n             = { parent~counter = #1 }
    , number within               .value_required:n   = true
    , shared~counter              .code:n             = { \crthm_counter_alias:en { \l__crthm_current_env_tl } { #1 } }
    , shared~counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , shared-counter              .meta:n             = { shared~counter = #1 }
    , shared-counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , shared counter              .meta:n             = { shared~counter = #1 }
    , shared counter              .value_required:n   = true
    , number~like                 .meta:n             = { shared~counter = #1 }
    , number~like                 .value_required:n   = true
    , number-like                 .meta:n             = { shared~counter = #1 }
    , number-like                 .value_required:n   = true
    , number like                 .meta:n             = { shared~counter = #1 }
    , number like                 .value_required:n   = true
    , unknown                     .code:n             = {}
  }
```

Comment: You've forgotten that `#1` will need braces around it: `, name-style    .meta:n             = { name~style = {#1} }`. Other than that, I would really encourage you not to have key names with spaces in them

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for this! May I ask why are the braces needed here, and what is the reason that you don't encourage key names with spaces in them?

Comment: Spaces in key names is a matter of style. As spaces are ignored in `expl3` code blocks, one ends up needing either `foo~bar` or `foo bar` depending on the context. There is also a tendency for spaces to be used in an inconsistent manner (some `pgf(plots)` keys suffer from this). Using hyphens avoids this risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documented behaviour of `l3key` is similar to other keyval packages: exactly one outer set of braces will be removed from a value *if present*. As such

```latex
foo = {bar} ,
```

and

```latex
foo = bar ,
```

are equivalent (as `l3keys` ignores leading and trailing spaces). This means that with a key setting such as

```latex
name-style = { % "name style" works
  , heading style = \color{blue}\textsc
  , crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
  , Crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
  , numbering style = \color{red}\textbf
    }
```

will remove the outer braces and pass

```latex
, heading style = \color{blue}\textsc
, crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
, Crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
, numbering style = \color{red}\textbf
```

as `#1` to `name-style`. This is then inserted into

```latex
name~style = #1
```

leading to

```
name~style = 
, heading style = \color{blue}\textsc
, crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
, Crefname style = \color{blue}\textsc
, numbering style = \color{red}\textbf
```

In other words, `name style` receives an empty value, and you set other keys directly.

The general conclusion is that when passing key values from one key to another, you should *always* use a set of braces to shield against `,` or `=` tokens

```latex
name-style .meta:n = { name~style = {#1} }
```